# Chamar função do c# de dentro de uma dll c++

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, c++-cli

Situação:

- Tenho um projeto em 3 camadas: Uma para dados, uma para interface gráfica em C# e outra em C++.
- A camada em c++ é feita usando o suporte a `clr` (*Suporte a Common Language Runtime* (/clr) ). Porém uso ela como `wrapper` entre minhas classes C++ puro e C#. Dentro desta camada uso VTK e ITK.
- A camada em C# faz a chamada para as demais então só ela enxerga as outras.
  Preciso atualizar algo que esta em um formulário na camada do C# indo pela camada do C++. C++ puro vai fazer chamar o método no formulário do C#.

Já pesquisei sobre o assunto e só encontrei exemplos de como fazer usando socket entre C# e C++. Esta opção não é muito valida pela curva que terei que ter no projeto.

Para a C++ referenciado eu consigo enviar o formulário sem problemas.

Como posso passar o gatilho da função C# para a C++ puro?

```
{
    FormCollection^ forms = Application::OpenForms;

    XNamespace::FormTeste^ frmTeste;

    for (int i = 0; i < forms->Count; i++)
    {
        if (forms[i]->Name == "FormTeste")
        {
            frmTeste = static_cast<XNamespace::FormTeste^>(forms[i]);
            frmTeste->GetUCCriarPanoramica()->DefinirEstadoCursorAxial(estado);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

no CLR consigo achar o formulário pelo nome, mas C++ puro não tem acesso a estas informações.

Comment: Existe, não há problema algum. Você está com algum problema?

Comment: Sim, eu não estou conseguindo fazer isto. Pode me ajudar? Com algum exemplo ou direcionamento?

Comment: @bigown  pode me da um direcionamento?

Comment: Leia o que está indicado acima, especialmente [ask].

Comment: @bigown obrigado pela dica. Já fiz as alterações para ser mais claro.

Comment: Você pode trabalhar com eventos ou troca de mensagens entre as camadas para indicar uma ação a ser executada, pois como você mesmo falou o fonte C++ puro não enxerga o código C#, só o contrário.

Comment: @BrunoBermann esta troca só teria como ser com um socket aberto do c# e consumido pelo c++ correto?

Comment: Existem N maneiras de implementar uma troca de mensagens... basta usar a imaginação. Alguns exemplos seriam a troca por socket, por arquivo (texto, binário, etc) ou mesmo por funções que retornam uma string ou outros valores significativos para tua implementação. No caso das funções o ideal é que fosse implementado em uma DLL para que todas as camadas tenham acesso a mesma interface de comunicação. Espero ter ajudado.